IF statement in HTML Template Giving blank output
Here is the formula I am trying I get the result in the formula field but it turn blank when I am using it in Email template
{!IF(Client_Life_Event__c.Legal_Business_Name__c,  
Client_Life_Event__c.Legal_Business_Name__c&"'s",
Client_Life_Event__c.Legal_Business_Name__c)}


What kind of email template? Text, HTML, Visualforce, Lightning? This also isn't a valid formula anywhere, assuming Legal Business Name is a text field.

Hi @sfdcfox  this is HTML template basically what we wanted is if this field is blank then in the template don't use apostrophe s after the field else juts the the legal business field

Classic templates (text, HTML, custom) do not support formulas. They're specifically called "merge fields" for a reason. Instead, use a Visualforce template, which does support formulas. Aside from that, the formula itself is wrong. You need to use a function that returns a Boolean value:
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Legal_Business_Name__c)),
  relatedTo.Legal_Business_Name__c & "'s",
  ""
)}


Thank you so much for the clarification :)
